# How to reactivate Google Chrome's pretty print?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've accidentally clicked the `never show` option for pretty print tool on Chrome when I was debugging an website and can't find the option to reactivate this feature again. Looked all over preferences and Googled it already, still no clue.

Comment: I guess you can reset devtools in its settings -> prefs -> restore

Comment: Well, it worked but I had to configure other changes I have done. It'd be great if there was just an option to enable again. Anyway, Thanks.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I'm not sure what panel of DevTools you're looking at. If it's the Sources panel, you can manually enable or disable pretty-printing by clicking **Format**.

[image: format]

In general, if you see that icon anywhere, clicking it will enable or disable pretty-printing.

Comment: I can't believe. I've just disabled the hint, not the tool itself... LOL. Shame on me. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

I just did the same thing because of the really poor UI there. There's another option before "never show" with no separator, which makes these look like "never" and "show" are 2 separate options, not a single "never show" one.

[image]

I did find the solution though. Shut down Chrome, go to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\` and edit the JSON file called `Preferences`. In it, find `prettyPrintInfobarDisabled` which will be set to `true` and change it back to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Dev tool > setting > Experiments > search 'pretty print' > check off!

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In version 121.0.6167.139 this switch is not present any more. I like to switch it off. So any idea how to do in the actual version? (It seems that this option is enabled by default and can not be deactivated for now...)